# Turtlebot tune gmapping

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we are using the turtlebot with a kinect and gmapping. But sometimes it do not updates the map (but the localcostmap and the laser see the walls and obstacles) but the Occupancy grid do not gets update.

How can we tune gmapping to improve the performance ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74992/turtlebot-tune-gmapping/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2013-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check also the map_update_interval parameter. I recently notice that it was set to 30 in turtlebot, what means only update every 30 seconds!!! The default value is 5 seconds.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0